# Any way to get Intel Graphics 3000 to run properly in Windows 10 version 1803?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, windows-10-v1803

I have an older HP i7 2nd gen laptop with Intel integrated graphics and a Radeon 6700m card. I recently updated (via a fresh install) to Windows 10 version 1803, and I am not able to set the resolution to 1080 even though the graphics card is capable of it.

For a while now I haven't been using the Radeon card as I had issues with it, but the Intel card was working properly. Now though Windows update apparently installed the latest driver for the Intel 3000, but I am getting reduced resolutions. When I tried downloading an official Intel driver, my computer would randomly start with a black screen. Any ideas or hacks?

Comment: See accepted answer at this link, simple registry hack fixed it for them...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d889c4a0-7aff-49ba-9b73-7b9e2ad5d8b7/intel-hd-graphics-driver-error-after-update-to-1803?forum=win10itprogeneral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 5/1/20**
This method is still working!

I solved my problem and just thought I would share my answer.

I uninstalled both the AMD driver and Intel driver using the DDU utility (Display Driver Uninstaller) which can be found easily online.

I then installed the Intel [UniFL Graphics Driver](http://leshcatlabs.net/downloads_unfil/) . Note, that when I tried to install the AMD UniFL driver, I was greeted to black screens. So I started over and uninstalled both and just reinstalled the Intel driver.

1080 resolution is now working and computer seems stable.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005526/graphics-drivers.html), the Intel HD Graphics 3000 is *not* supported under Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I noticed that on Intel's website, but it has been working properly up until this build...

Comment: Perhaps so, but I think that simply means that you were working on borrowed time up until now.

Comment: FWIW, I'm still running HD 3000 on my i7-2600K with Win 10 (v 1909) in July 2020. I'd like to update to WDDM 2.0 (from 1.2) doesn't look like it's available :-/